# UniswapV2 Router2 Interface

Tags: solidity, remix

I want to fetch getAmountsOut from UniswapV2 Router02 with

```
 // SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.10;



interface IUniswapV2Router {
    function getAmountsOut(
        uint256 amountIn,
        address[] memory path
    ) external view returns (uint256[] memory amounts);

 }



contract TwoDexArbitrage {
    

    function getAmountOutMin(address router, address _tokenIn, address _tokenOut, uint256 _amount) public view returns (uint256) {
        address[] memory path;
        path = new address[](2);
        path[0] = _tokenIn;
        path[1] = _tokenOut;
        uint256[] memory amountOutMins = IUniswapV2Router(router).getAmountsOut(_amount, path);
        return amountOutMins[path.length -1];
    }

    
}
```

getting

The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
Whenever arguments are passed from remix ide

```
(router: 0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D, 
  tokenIn:0xdAC17F958D2ee523a2206206994597C13D831ec7,
  tokenOut: 0x514910771AF9Ca656af840dff83E8264EcF986CA 
  amount:1000000)
```

on Sepolia testNetwork